# Empty body getting sent on using PUT method through android Volley

Tags: java, android, android-volley, put

I am using Volley to fetch data from a REST service. So there are two methods , One is POST which creates an object on server and other is PUT which basically updates the same object.I use the same code for making these requests.I just change the Method which is passed in Volley.The app works fine through POST request with the correct data sent in the body, but it encounters a problem with PUT request where it randomly sends no data in the body.

I shifted to a custom Request object as suggested by Google but it is still not working.

```
    int method = Request.Method.POST;

    String objID = sharedPreferences.getString("objID", null);
    String Url = "/api_url";

    if (objID != null)
    {
        Url += objID + "/";
        method = Request.Method.PUT;
    }

    try
    {
        JSONObject objJSON = new JSONObject();
        objJSON.put("name", "new_name");
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        // Handle Execption
    }

    GsonRequest request = new GsonRequest<CustomObj>(method, Url, CustomObj.class,null, null, objJSON.toString(),
    new Response.Listener<CustomObj>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(CartObj cartObj)
        {
            // Handling Logic
        }
    }
    ,
    new Response.ErrorListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError)
        {
            // Handle Error   
        }
    });

    VolleySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

GsonRequest is my Custom Class Extending Request Object

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T>
{
    private final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final Map<String, String> headers;
    private final Listener<T> listener;
    private final Map<String, String> params;
    private final String body;
    private ErrorListener mErrorListener;

    /**
     * Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
     *
     * @param url     URL of the request to make
     * @param clazz   Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
     * @param headers Map of request headers
     */

    public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> params, String body, Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)
    {
        super(method, url, errorListener);
        this.clazz = clazz;
        this.headers = headers;
        this.listener = listener;
        this.params = params;
        this.body = body;
        this.mErrorListener = errorListener;
    }

    public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers, Map<String, String> params, Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)
    {
        this(method, url, clazz, headers, params, null, listener, errorListener);
    }

    public GsonRequest(int method, String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers, Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener)
    {
        this(method, url, clazz, headers, null, null, listener, errorListener);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError
    {
        return body != null ? body.getBytes() : super.getBody();
    }

    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError
    {
        return params != null ? params : super.getParams();
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError
    {
        return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
    }


    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(T response)
    {
        listener.onResponse(response);
    }

    @Override
    public void deliverError(VolleyError error)
    {
        mErrorListener.onErrorResponse(error);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response)
    {
        try
        {
            String json = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(gson.fromJson(json, clazz), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
        catch (JsonSyntaxException e)
        {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        }
    }
}
```

I am using GSON to parse my Data , and CustomObj is a Mapping Object for volley.

Answer (score 0):

First of all all make sure the url you're building (where you check if `objID` is not null) is correct.

Secondly, you can try to call `getBytes()` method with a charset.

In the request override `getBody()` method:

```
@Override
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    try {
        return body != null ? body.getBytes(getParamsEncoding()) : super.getBody();
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return super.getBody();
}
```

Hope this will help.

**Edit:**

You can also try to override `getBodyContentType()` method:

```
@Override
public String getBodyContentType() {
    return "application/json; charset=" + getParamsEncoding();
}
```

Comment: so the url is correct and everything works , but randomly. the same call will work sometimes and send put data, other times it will not . I will try the above sol'n and check.

Comment: it did not work. I added these , but still giving the same error. Can it be a problem of android .